# Compare two lists in python and obtain non-equality

Tags: python, list, recursion, tweepy

This piece of code in theory have to compare two lists which have the ID of a tweet, and in this comparison if it already exists in screen printing , otherwise not.
But I print all or not being listed.
Any suggestions to compare these two lists of ID's and if not the ID of the first list in the second then print it ?
Sorry for the little efficient code . ( and my English )

What I seek is actually not do RT ( retweet ) repeatedly when I already have . I use Tweepy library , I read the timeline , and make the tweet RT I did not do RT

```
def analizarRT():
    timeline = []
    temp = []
    RT = []
    fileRT = openFile('rt.txt')
    for status in api.user_timeline('cnn', count='6'):
        timeline.append(status)
    for i in range(6):
        temp.append(timeline[i].id)
    for a in range(6):
        for b in range(6):
            if str(temp[a]) == fileRT[b]:
                pass
            else:
                RT.append(temp[a])
    for i in RT:
        print i
```

Solved add this function !

```
def estaElemento(tweetId, arreglo):
    encontrado = False
    for a in range(len(arreglo)):
         if str(tweetId) == arreglo[a].strip():
            encontrado = True
            break
return encontrado
```

Comment: Please edit the question and fix the indent error.

Comment: Can you please clearly explain, which list you are trying to compare against which other list? I only see one list in the code.

Comment: List 1 -> timeline, List 2 -> fileRT...anyway it is indifferent , fileRT has 6 elements (ID ) to compare with each list item timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple program, don't complicate it. As per your comments, there are two lists:)

**1. timeline**

**2. fileRT**

Now, you want to compare the **id's** in both these lists. Before you do that, you must know the nature of these two lists.

**I mean, what is the type of data in the lists?**

> Is it
>
> 1. list of strings? or
> 2. list of objects? or
> 3. list of integers?

So, find out that, debug it, or use print statements in your code. Or please add these details in your question. So, you can give a perfect answer.

Mean while, try this:

`if timeline.id == fileRT.id` should work.

Edited:

```
def analizarRT():
    timeline = []
    fileRT = openFile('rt.txt')
    for status in api.user_timeline('cnn', count='6'):
        timeline.append(status)
    for i in range(6):
        for b in range(6):
            if timeline[i].id == fileRT[b].id:
                pass
            else:
                newlist.append(timeline[i].id)
    print newlist
```

As per your question, you want to obtain them, right?. I have appended them in a **newlist**. Now you can say `print newlist` to see the items

Comment: Thanks for the reply. very instructive.

Comment: Add some details dude, we can get this thing done :)

Comment: Thanks you Shiva Shinde !. Great Idea's....my data is different !
<type 'str'>
<type 'int'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'int'>

Comment: So, you mean this **list = ['Shiva', 123, 'Shinde', 456]**

and both timeline & fileRT are in same format?

Comment: Please try the above code, let me know if its working :)

Comment: Negative values ​​keeps repeating , it does not recognize that the values ​​are repeated !! ... Grrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: Add this above your nested-for-loop **print timeline[0].id**, see what it prints. In the same way, **print fileRT[0].id** and see what it prints

Answer (score 0):

your else statement is associated with the for statement, you probably need to add one more indent to make it work on the if statement.